# PHP Calculate latest delivery day based on lead time (in days) and possible delivery days

Tags: php, laravel

I'll start with the lead time, this field is a `number` (say `5`) in number of days.

I also have an `array` of weekdays that I can possible deliver on where `1 = true` and `0 = false`

```php
"monday" => 1,
"tuesday" => 1,
"wednesday" => 0,
"thursday" => 1,
"friday" => 1,
"saturday" => 1,
"sunday" => 0,
```

Now I want to make a function where I can fill in the total number of days and automatically calculates the date in the following output:

```php
Carbon::now()->translatedFormat('l j F');
```

```php
public static function createLatestDeliveryDate($profile_id, $days)
{
    $addDays = $days;

    $delivery = CustomerProfileDelivery::where('customer_profile_id', $profile_id)
        ->first();

    return Carbon::now()->translatedFormat('l j F');
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? What error do you have?

Comment: What I want is to calculate the day that the delivery will take place based on the number of days. Suppose it is now February 20 and the delivery time is 2 days. Then the output should be Wednesday, February 22. But it could be that Wednesday is not a delivery day because in the array that day is set to 0. The output should then be February 23. How can i create a function that would calculate that and returns the right date. Hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your comment to your question. Well for starters, it's going to be a recursive function, you start with a calculated day, pass it on to a function to check if that day is a delivery day, if so, return that day, if not, pass it on to the same function with the next day and do this over and over again until you find a delivery day.

Comment: @jkoopman you have to try something and then come to us if you can't make it work. This is no a tutorials site where you ask what you want and we do it, that is why I am asking what errors do you have

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
private $delivery_days = ["monday" => 1,
"tuesday" => 1,
"wednesday" => 0,
"thursday" => 1,
"friday" => 1,
"saturday" => 1,
"sunday" => 0];

protected function get_delivery_day($days) {
 $date = Carbon::now();
 $date->addDays(days);
 if($this->delivery_days[strtolower($date->englishDayOfWeek)]) { // lower casing just because your array is like that
 return $date->translatedFormat('l j F');
 }else{
  return $this->get_delivery_day($days++);
}
```